# Apollo GraphQL schema + codegen converting Hasura/PostgreSQL scalar array to scalar

Tags: graphql, apollo, hasura

I'm using Hasura to provide a GraphQL interface to a PostgreSQL table. If I have a table with an `integer[]` column, the command `apollo schema:download` is generating a `schema.json` with:

```
      {
        "name": "distances",
        "description": null,
        "type": {
          "kind": "SCALAR",
          "name": "_int4",
          "ofType": null
        },
        "defaultValue": null
      }
```

which is unfortunate because it doesn't convey the information that this field is an array. Naturally, when I use `apollo codegen:generate` the type is either morphed into `String` or just `_int4` if using the `--passthroughCustomScalars` flag.

Is there a way to configure my graphql server (Hasura) or the apollo CLI to preserve the array type information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `_` prefix can already be an indicator of an array type. I'm not sure if other scenarios could lead to a type name `_int4` but in my use-case I can safely assume that `int4` comes from `Integer` while `_int4` comes from `Integer[]`.

This way I can use `--passthroughCustomScalars` and provide type aliases for my Apollo SDK to recognize the `_int4` output from `apollo codegen:generate` as an integer array and define the appropriate JSON encode/decode methods. Somewhat a rough edge on the code generation tooling, but manageable.